# How to use DISTINCT for just one field when ORDER BY another field is used?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-order-by, distinct

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 SP2.

I want to use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PortalURI
FROM LoginHistory
ORDER BY LastLoginDate DESC
```

But it tells me that it requires `LastLoginDate` field to be selected too like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PortalURI, LastLoginDate
FROM LoginHistory
ORDER BY LastLoginDate DESC
```

But it gives me repeated `PortalURI`.

How can i keep `PortalURI` distinct?

**Edit:** I also used `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY MAX(LastLoginDate)` but the result was this exception:

> Expressions in the ORDER BY list cannot contain aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT PortalURI, MAX(LastLoginDate) LastLoginDate
FROM LoginHistory
GROUP BY PortalURI
ORDER BY LastLoginDate DESC
```

Comment: Edited to name the column, and undeleted to try again :)

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot! I Marked it as answer

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
SELECT PortalURI
FROM LoginHistory
GROUP BY PortalURI
ORDER BY MAX(LastLoginDate) DESC
```

**EDIT:** SQL Server Compact Edition does not support aggregate functions on the ORDER BY clause. So, here is an alternative solution:

```
SELECT PortalURI, MAX(LastLoginDate)
FROM LoginHistory
GROUP BY PortalURI
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: **Exception:** "Expressions in the ORDER BY list cannot contain aggregate functions."

Please mention that i use **SQL Server Compact Edition**.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Compact Edition.  Would this work `SELECT PortalURI, MAX(LastLoginDate)
FROM LoginHistory
GROUP BY PortalURI
ORDER BY 2 DESC`?

Comment: On VisualStudio works fine but on **ADO.NET (C#)** shows exception: "ORDER BY <column number> not supported."

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT PortalURI, MAX(LastLoginDate)
    FROM LoginHistory
    GROUP BY PortalURI
    ORDER BY LastLoginDate DESC
```

Comment: **Exception:** "In aggregate and grouping expressions, the ORDER BY clause can contain only aggregate functions and grouping expressions."

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT PortalURI,max(LastLoginDate)
FROM LoginHistory
GROUP BY PortalURI
ORDER BY LastLoginDate DESC
```

Comment: **Exception:** "Expressions in the ORDER BY list cannot contain aggregate functions."

Please mention that i use **SQL Server Compact Edition**.

Comment: **Exception:** "In aggregate and grouping expressions, the ORDER BY clause can contain only aggregate functions and grouping expressions."